# What is the proper location for libraries in an ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

If I create a custom routing class, what's the typical convention for where it's located in an  ASP.NET MVC project?

(Note that these are not domain-specific libraries as they are implementations of ASP.NET MVC's interfaces to hook the lifecycle.)

Comment: I typically keep libraries in separate projects and reference them in the MVC project.  If you wanted to simply make a folder in the project, that would work as well, but it will make it harder to reuse if you do that.

Comment: I guess the thing is that the libraries I'm making are specific to my project, so locating them in another dll would be pointless?

Comment: I don't think so.  It's just another way to organize things.  I keep my libraries separate with separate test projects for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I preder to keep them in a separate project with folder for every kind.
For example for an MVC projects I usually do:

```
 MyCompany.MyApp.Web.MVC
```

and then the helpers

```
MyCompany.MyApp.Web.MVC.Helpers
          AttributeHelpers
          RoutingHelpers
          HtmlHelpers
```

Answer (score 2):

For me, best place for those kind of classes is kind of separate `Infrastructure`-named project. Those Infrastructure-projects contain general helper libraries. Web knows about Infrastructure, but not vice-versa. Even Microsoft has that kind of naming convention. Namespace for custom route class may be `*.Web.Infrastructure.Routing`

Comment: @Omega -  if, like me, you don't want to see the word `Infrastructure` in your project, use `Framework`; it's synonymous (http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/infrastructure)